# What will be the SQL oracle query for finding out the maximum experience from hire date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Have to find the most experienced employee.

```
select empno, ename, 
from emp
where max(months_between(SYSDATE,hiredate))
```

My software is giving errors on sysdate, so could anyone please verify if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select e.empno, e.ename 
from emp e
where not exists (select 1 from emp where hiredate < e.hiredate)
```

or:

```
select empno, ename 
from emp 
where hiredate = (select min(hiredate) from emp)
```

or modify the `WHERE` clause of your query like this:

```
select empno, ename 
from emp 
where months_between(SYSDATE, hiredate) = (
  select max(months_between(SYSDATE, hiredate)) 
  from emp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select e.*
from emp e
order by hiredate asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want duplicates, then add `with ties`.

The above works in Oracle 12C+.  In earlier versions, you need a subquery:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (order by hiredate) as seqnum
      from emp e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```